# insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!

Tags: logging, glassfish, elasticsearch

I have installed ELK Stack 6.7.1 in a VPS and the agent filebeat in another vps which has running glassfish 4.1 and grafana running but running filebeat to dump the glassfish logs:

```
sudo update-rc.d filebeat defaults 95 10
```

throws me this error:

```
insserv: warning: script 'K01glassfish' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'glassfish' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service grafana if started
insserv: There is a loop between service grafana and mountnfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs at depth 8
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs-bootclean at depth 10
insserv: There is a loop between service glassfish and mountall if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountall at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot-bootclean at depth 5
insserv: There is a loop between service glassfish and mountall-bootclean if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountall-bootclean at depth 7
insserv: There is a loop between service glassfish and mountall if started
insserv: There is a loop between service grafana and mountdevsubfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service mysql at depth 1
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 9
insserv: There is a loop between service grafana and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 4
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting glassfish depends on grafana-server and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was able to resolve this issue. It was that if grafana was installed on the server only that the development team ignored it or thought it was uninstalled, in addition to that I have been working with them for a short time. I could find the grafana service configured at startup but disabled. It was necessary to remove it so that the problem disappeared.